# Power Query - Yahoo - HTTP 301 Error

Tags: excel, http-status-code-301, yahoo-finance, powerquery

I have a problem which was discussed in an other thread but while the author said he solved it is - for me at least - quit unclear how he did it.

Other thread: [Yahoo finance historical stock price power query returns 301 response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43904268/yahoo-finance-historical-stock-price-power-query-returns-301-response)

I use Power Query an Add In for Excel which allows different query's, one is to grab website content, which I automated for yahoo data. Unfortunately it seems something changed with the yahoo site index and I am not able to use my query anymore.

If I try to recreate the query (build it from scratch again) I get the error "HTTP 301". Even with the "normal" query feature of excel the yahoo data is not available anymore.

Hopefully someone is able to help me.

Best wishes,
Andreas

Answer (score 0):

## You should set header "user-agent" to emulate browser

For examble Google Chrome

```
let
    url = "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAL/history?p=AAL",
    #"user-agent"="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.86 Safari/537.36",
    web = Web.Contents(url, [Headers=[#"user-agent"=#"user-agent"]]),
    html = Web.Page(web),
    Data0 = html{0}[Data]
in
    Data0
```

[image]